# Creating first module, and How to alter text field on new content creation in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I am trying to set the text in a custom content field when saving a node. I think I need to create a module to do this. (I am new to module creation.)

I started with a blank directory called - let's say `myModule`. I placed `myModule` into path `sites/all/modules`.

I placed into the myModule directory two files that I understand to be required and gave them the following naming conventions which I also believe to be the standard:
myModule.module
myModule.info

```
myModule.info holds the following text:   
name = Some Descriptive Name   
description = does stuff.   
package = relatedName   
core = 7.x
```

Inside `myModule.module` I have tried various things that are to much to elaborate , but include these exact functions and parameters.

**Attempt 1:**

```
function myModule_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {   
    if ($node->type == 'theNameOfACustomContentTypeICreated'){   
        foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {   
          //I am ver unclear at this point, and this function does not seem to be called when creating new content.   
        }   
    }
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
myModule_nodeapi($node){   
    //this function does not seem to be called when creating new content.   
}
```

I am at a loss. Neither function is even getting called - nor working.

**Edit, the issue is resolved.** The correct start was hook_jba_node_presave($node) , but I had syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pointers:

- Use only lower case for module names.
- `$node` is not available in [`hook_field_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7). `$entity` should contain necessary info.
- `hook_nodeapi()` is not available in Drupal 7.
- It's possible you can make these alterations in your theme's `template.php` file as well.

You can use the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to help with debugging, e.g. `dpm($entity, '$entity contains')`.

Also see [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) and [Drupal 7 API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve your goal of saving a value to a field without writing a custom module is to use the [Computed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field).

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed   fields" to your content types. These computed
>   fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may
>   draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the
>   current user, database tables, you name it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [module creating guide](http://drupal.org/node/1074362) for module names (applies to the names of your functions, too).
Then try to go through the hooks for nodes - just enter "hook_node_" into the search box @ [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal).
I guess one of these could be useful to you :

- [hook_node_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7)
- [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)

good luck :).